# How to solve cystal report format using group

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

[image]

### I am facing group problem.I need Class wise Sub Class Total .I am passing datatable like

| Class 1  |Sub Class 1 |20 |

| Class 1  |Sub Class 2 |50 |

| Class 1  |Sub Class 3 |40 |

now i need to show report using cystal report.Any one help me with details.

Comment: you simply need a group total. if you put the total field in the group footer it will only total for the current group. So each new group it will reset to 0 automatically.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?